# What is the meaning of the differential in Doran and Lasenby's discussion of Noether's theorem for spacetime transformations?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, differentiation, variational-calculus, clifford-algebra

Doran and Lasenby (*Geometric Algebra for Physicists,* pg. 450) state that if a transformation involves spacetime dependence (this brings to my mind common examples: translation and rotation), then Noether's theorem applies and we can define

$$\psi^\prime (x) = \psi(x^\prime)$$

where

$$ x^\prime = f(x) $$

What I do not understand, is where they say

> "The differential is defined in the usual way as"
> $$ \texttt{f}(a) = a \cdot \nabla f(x). $$

So this is a directional derivative in the direction "$a$".

For more context, they go on to say that the transformed action is $$S=\int d^4x \mathcal{L} \left(\psi(x^\prime)\right) = \int d^4 x^\prime \det (\texttt{f})^{-1} \mathcal{L}\left(\psi(x^\prime)\right).$$

Is this differential, that has some parameter $a$, for translations only, or is it for any spacetime transformation?

For a translation, I think we must have $x^\prime = x + b$ while a rotation would be parameterised by both an angle and bivector. Is there a relationship between $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text can be a little confusing, in that arguments to functions are sometimes put in (so you know it's a function) and sometimes left out (to simplify unwieldy expressions), not always entirely consistently.

The differential being defined is the *function* $\texttt{f}$. This function takes a vector as an argument and returns the *directional derivative* of $f$ in the direction of that vector. The $a$ is just a dummy variable used in the definition, a placemarker for the argument of the function.

This is geometric algebra's approach to 1-forms, (also known as dual vectors, or covectors). Differential geometry defines a 1-form as a linear function that takes a vector and returns a scalar. It has the effect of taking the dot product with a fixed vector, in spaces with dot products. It then treats these 1-forms as a new sort of vector in a dual space $V^*$ associated with the vector space $V$, and distinguishes them with the upper and lower indices of tensors. Geometric algebra usually doesn't use this approach; it continues to write them as functions of vectors (or more generally of multivectors). A 1-form $f$ can be written as a linear function $f(v)=k\cdot v$ where $k$ is a constant vector and $v$ is the vector argument to the function.

The differential is more properly a 1-form, so we convert the gradient vector $\nabla f$ of the transformation $f$ to a 1-form $\texttt{f}$ using this technique.

There is no relationship between your $a$ and $b$, they can vary independently. If $f_b(x)=x+b$ is a family of transformations of space (the translations) then each member of the family has a differential $\texttt{f}_b$ defined as $\texttt{f}_b(a) = a \cdot \nabla f_b$.

And it applies to any spacetime transformation, not just translations.

Answer (score 1):

This differential is for any spacetime transformation. Note that $f(x)$ is a vector, so $\nabla f(x)$ is a "matrix", not a vector. Then $\mathrm{f}$ is a linear operator acting on vectors, such as $a$, and yielding a vector. Then $\det(\mathrm{f})$ is a Jacobian. I would say there is no relationship between $a$ and $b$ as $a$ is always arbitrary (it is used just to define the action of the operator on an arbitrary vector), while $b$ is fixed for a fixed translation.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to make sense of it as being for any spacetime transformation. By GA operator precedence and notation, $a$ is a vector, the dot evaluates first to a scalar $a \cdot \nabla$, so there may be a matrix-like metric scalar as an intermediate step but overall $\texttt{f}(a)$ is a vector.

Comment: For future readers of this question, there is a lot of explanation regarding this question on pg. 214 of Doran and Lasenby.